# Java renaming files in directory doesn't work properly

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to rename to upper case all the files in a given directory. It does the whole thing but it doesn't do anything in the folder file names are still the same .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileOps {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        File folder = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                File f = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files"
                            + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                f.renameTo(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files"
                            + listOfFiles[i].getName().toUpperCase()
                            + ".txt"));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

It prints "Done" in the console but nothing is really done

Comment: It's not such file in the directory, so maybe really it is because of the OS I am with Windows 8

Comment: Windows can be funny about renames that only modify the case. Try renaming them to something else completely (for example add an _ at the start) and then rename them back with the case changed. (Obviously you will need to cope with cases where there are already files called _x)

Comment: Instead of renaming you can try to move these files. It worked for me.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` statement, you forgot to add ending separator:

```
 if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        File f = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files\\"// <- Missing separator
                        + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        f.renameTo(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files\\"// <- Missing separator
                        + listOfFiles[i].getName().toUpperCase()
                        + ".txt"));
 }
```

A proper implemntation would be:

```
if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
         listOfFiles[i].renameTo(new File(folder, listOfFiles[i].getName().toUpperCase()+ ".txt"));//not sure why this .txt
```

Be careful, the `renameTo` method is highly platform dependent. Read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following to check what is happening. Some small changes include using the `File(parent,name)` form to avoid having to determine and add the OS specific file path separator.

```
package com.example.renaming;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestRename {
    private static final String[] defaultArgs = { "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files" };
    private static TestRename me;
    private static String[] arguments;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        me = new TestRename();
        if (args == null | args.length == 0) {
            arguments = defaultArgs;
        } else {
            arguments = args;
        }
        me.doWork(arguments);

    }

    private void doWork(String[] arguments) {
        int numFiles = 0;
        File folder = new File(arguments[0]);

        try {
            System.out.println("Working on " + folder.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
        if (fileList == null) {
            System.out.println("No files fould");
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("File " + fileList[i].getName());
                if (fileList[i].isFile()) {
                    numFiles++;
                    try {
                        String currentName = fileList[i].getName();
                        File parent = fileList[i].getParentFile();
                        String newName = currentName.toUpperCase() + ".txt";
                        System.out.println(" .. current = " + currentName);
                        System.out.println(" .. newname = " + newName);

                        // Avoids having to get the file path separator for an OS
                        File newFile = new File(parent, newName);
                        System.out.println(" .. new File = "
                                + newFile.getCanonicalPath());
                        fileList[i].renameTo(newFile);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Done, found " + numFiles);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [ortis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722631/978501), you have missed to add "\" while naming files.

```
                f.renameTo(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files"
                        + listOfFiles[i].getName().toUpperCase()
                        + ".txt"));
```

executing this code over and over will result in adding .txt to the file names. You can consider using apache [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) for getting extention.

Making those changes to your code,

```
File folder = new File("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/pics");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for(File file : listOfFiles){
    if(file.isFile()){          
        String fileName =   FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName()).toUpperCase() ; 
        String newPath = folder + File.separator + fileName+ "."+ FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
        file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I add it to my project with gradle?